# Auto zoom to current location is not working properly for particular area

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using react-native-maps, I have been showing maps with current location, Zoom level looks good for some location, and for some location, map looks blurry. I tried calculating the `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` value following [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/505#issuecomment-243423775) link, but no luck. How to zoom map at city level?

This is my code

```
let region = {
  latitude: this.props.latitude,
  longitude: this.props.longitude,
  latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
  longitudeDelta: 0.0421
}; 


<MapView
  style={[styles.map, {flex: 3, height: deviceHeight / 50, width: deviceWidth}]}
  region={this.state.mapRegion}
  showsUserLocation={true}
  followUserLocation={true}
  initialRegion={this.state.initialRegion}
  onRegionChangeComplete={mapRegion => {
    this.updateAddress(mapRegion);
}}>
  <MapView.Marker
    coordinate={{
      latitude: this.state.mapRegion ? this.state.mapRegion.latitude : this.state.latitude,
      longitude: this.state.mapRegion ? this.state.mapRegion.longitude : this.state.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421
  }}>
    </MapView.Marker>
</MapView>
```

[blurry map image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xobs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use animateToRegion() method which me help you.

```
this.mapView.animateToRegion(initialRegion, 2000); // pass your region object as first parameter
```

Comment: I tried animateToRegion() method, it just animate to current location but no changes in zoom level. I want to show zoom as city level.